How to search additional field in single-page app using GraphQL
I have taken over a Craft CMS project from a previous developer, and I'm having trouble implementing a new simple feature on a single-page app, which is to have search queries match recipe ingredients (in addition to the recipe titles).
On the Recipes page https://marzetti-fs-staging.cl-us-east-3.servd.dev/recipes in the left sidebar (not the search input in the header), there is a 'Search Recipes' function, which searches recipes in the Craft database.
The 'Filter App' coded in Vue.js (https://marzetti-fs-staging.cl-us-east-3.servd.dev/dist/filterApp.js) has a GraphQL query, which I have little experience in both.
In the App.vue file, (which I believe is the source file before being compiled into JS) originally contained the following:
const RECIPE_QUERY = gql`
    {
        entries(section: "recipes", orderBy: "title") {
            id
            title
            slug
            uri
            status

            ... on recipes_default_Entry {
                id
                cookTime
                yieldWeight
                recipeTags {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }
                description
                portionWeight
                prepTime
                recipeImage
                servings
                slug
                status
                title               
                recipeMenuItems {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }
                recipeSegments {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }
                recipeBrands {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }
                recipeFlavors {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }
                recipeDaypart {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }   
            }
        }
    }
`;

The ingredients field 'recipeIngredients' I'm trying to include in the search is a 'table' type field, has a column named ingredientName (single-line text type) which I added to the query, like so:
const RECIPE_QUERY = gql`
    {
        entries(section: "recipes", orderBy: "title") {
            id
            title
            slug
            uri
            status

            ... on recipes_default_Entry {
                id
                cookTime
                yieldWeight
                recipeTags {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }
                description
                portionWeight
                prepTime
                recipeImage
                servings
                slug
                status
                title               
                recipeMenuItems {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }
                recipeSegments {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }
                recipeBrands {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }
                recipeFlavors {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }
                recipeDaypart {
                    slug
                    title
                    status
                }   

                // added new field below
                recipeIngredients {
                    ingredientName
                }

            }
        }
    }
`; 

With the little research I have done on GraphQL, I learned the query is setting which data to request from the API (and not actually a query).
I was hoping someone could advise me how to include the recipeIngredients.ingredientName field to be included in search queries. Thanks in advance.
